# May I use a integration limit on scipy cumtrapz?

Tags: python, scipy

When I use cumtrapz the calculated area is limited by the XX axis. Is it possible to be limited by x=10, for instance?

Thank you

Hugo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `x` argument:

```
scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(y, x=range(low_lim, high_lim+1))
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html

To limit your integration to y_min and y_max, when you have a list of definite values (not a function), you'll need to do some manual work.

The goal will be to change the values of your y-list to actually contain he samples you'd like to integrate.

So,

```
y_min = 10
y_max = 50
y_list = [100*sin(x) for x in range (0,100)]

mod_y = [0 if y < y_min else y - y_min for y in y_list]
mod_y = [y_max - y_min if y > y_max else y - y_min for y in mod_y]

scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(mod_y)
```

The subtraction on the comprehensions is to bring your minimum down to zero, which is what cumtrapz calculates anyway.

Comment: Using your answer, am I limiting the y values or the x values?

Comment: X values, as is usually the case with integration limits.

Comment: Thank you. Probably I am not understanding the problem. What I want to do is to calculate degree-days in a more precise way, like in: http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/WEATHER/ddconcepts.html

Comment: What input do you have? A list of y values? A function? There's not nearly enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: A list of temperatures with a 15min interval timestamp

Comment: And what output do you want?

Comment: The area under the temperature line, limited by two y values, as in the UC Davis link that I've sent to you.

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it answers your question, please accept it.